# Race condition issue in review window? "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit"

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I just tried to edit [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025624/how-do-i-can-use-machine-language-without-using-the-assembler-and-operating-syst) by **deleting** the unrelated [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) tag used there. The edit got rejected almost instantly because Community **edited in** a different tag instead of just deleting it. Obviously, this makes sense because they can make changes instantly while mine was pending review, so no question there.

BUT, this is what [my edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/8560676) looks like now:

[image: Screenshot of review window]

It looks like I was trying to delete their inserted [machine-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-code) tag! At the same time it's obvious that my edit came earlier (4 mins old vs. Community's 3 mins) and I am very sure that this tag was not there before, but that I deleted the [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) one instead. So, my questions are:

1. What is going on here? Why would the edits be merged this way? (Especially, because it makes mine look plain stupid... -_-')
2. What does the edit history look like for high-rep users? Can the full, 'real' story be seen there? Because this is all I see even though it's my edit.

I would have expected my edit with a red field for [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) on the left and the edit it conflicted with on the right with red for [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning) and green for [machine-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-code) or something like that.

Comment: You should still be able to view the [revision history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31025624/revisions).

Comment: Of course, but the history only shows edits that have been approved of, so my suggestion is not in there.

Comment: I know, that is the window that I took a screenshot of and that is posted above. The question is not where to find my rejected edit, but why it shows information that is wrong because I did not try to edit out their tag, but wanted to remove a different one that is not shown anymore.

Comment: I see the same edit history you do.  Honestly, I'm surprised that the other user's edit didn't suppress your edit from being submitted in the first place.  When there are concurrent edits, you can only edit "if your edit is more substantial".  So your suggested edit should have been disallowed on the front end (since the other user's edit was more substantial).  Instead it got processed as just a tag removal.  Weird.

Comment: But that's all my edit was, just a tag removal -- only for a different tag. So I do understand that it got rejected with the next edit being more substantial and coming from a user with higher rep, but I don't understand the summary I see... And when you say "disallowed", what exactly do you mean? Are there things that can happen to a suggested edit other than being approved or rejected?

Comment: Well when another user starts editing the same post that I'm editing, a notification bar appears alerting me that my edits will only take place if my edits are more substantial than the other user's edits.  I thought it would automatically suppress the edit if I fail to make a "more substantial" edit, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @ryanyuyu That bar apparently failed today because it normally appears, but that might as well have been my internet connection. I absolutely wasn't aware of the other user's edit and mine should not have been processed because it was based on something that didn't exist any more. Interesting...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It wasn't Community that edited the question, Community is simply an automated process that, among other things, does stuff to make things not get screwed up, such as rejecting edits that would cause conflicts.

If you check [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31025624/revisions), you'll see an edit by Alex K. at 11:55:27, while your suggestion was at 11:57:04 (and auto-rejected at 11:57:19). Your edit was based on the original version but was suggested after someone else' edit, so it was automatically rejected.

The revision history compares the post-edit version with the changes you made, so it can look like you actually made the question look worse - this is not ideal behaviour, but it gets auto-rejected, so I don't see a big problem here.

Since you only edited the tags, the changes Alex made in the body is not shown in the diff.

Revision history looks the same to high-rep users as it does to you AFAIK.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense... Unfortunately, I cannot follow the history because all I see in the revision history is the approved edit you mentioned, but not my own edit suggestion. It only appears in my own list of actions, but not with accurate times, it only tells me that it was two hours ago.

Comment: @FranzWurst hover over the time ("proposed 2 hours ago"), and the tooltip will give you an exact timestamp.

Comment: @FranzWurst also, notice the rejection reason is "This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit."  Not a big deal.  It's not rejected for something like "No improvement" or even "Vandalism"

Comment: @ryanyuyu aHA! Thanks, that's a nice feature I didn't know about. :)

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm not really worried about the rejection itself, SO is hopefully not going to ban me tonight... I was just curious about the looks of the suggestion and

Comment: @Dukeling even though it's not a big problem I do find it somewhat confusing, simply because it's wrong. But thanks for shedding some light on this!

Comment: @FranzWurst yeah good luck.  You (probably?) won't be banned for just 2 rejected suggestions.