# What is the policy of Suggested Edits Reviewers on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

I believe deeply in this community and every day I try to contribute with my grain of sand. But really there are things I do not understand. When a question is protected, comments like: **"Thanks to you..."**, **"Thanks in advance.."**, ..., are not allowed therefore I think the goal is to avoid such sentences in questions, answers or comments.

Lately I have spent some time to suggest edits on some questions, and many of these issues have to do with the presence of these judgments on users type. Personally do not like because it removes presence to question, I think there are other ways to thank.

Some of my suggestions are accepted, others are rejected for reasons such as:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.
>
> This edit conflicted with a subsequent edit.

I am on the point of not suggest more edits of this type.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297693/race-condition-issue-in-review-window-this-edit-conflicted-with-a-subsequent-e

Comment: A lot of your recent rejected edits were because of other conflicting edits. (If it says rejected by community) For some of the others try to fix everything thats wrong, not just removing the thank you. If you just missed one spelling issue I'd probably accept and edit, but if you missed a bunch of other stuff, Id certainly reject. (Probably reject and edit so you can see the corrections)

Comment: comments like: "Thanks to you...", "Thanks in advance.." are not allowed regardless of whether a question is protected or not, by the way.

Comment: I think it is arbitrary as to what an accepted edit should be. For example, I am on a 3 day review ban for accepting an edit that backticked code inline with text because I thought it was a good addition to the post. The reason for ban was because they said the user was trying to "bump" the post, although as far as I could tell the user had no attachment to that post besides his edit.  He contributed no comment, and no answer to this old post, so I do not see his attachment or investment. This is kind of a rant. If anything the guy was trying to bump his edit score. I'm done suggesting edits.

Comment: One thing to remember is part of the reason for the pickiness of the review queue for suggested edits is that they take up the time of others to review and to accept, reject or improve so it is better to make sure they are worthwhile.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the ONLY thing you remove is

> Thanks very much in advance for any assistance! :)

you are running the risk of an rejection because not all reviewers in the suggested edits queue  like to review edits that are mindless edits to only fix specific errors. If they find anything else you could have fixed as well they might reject. (but the suggested edits queue is known for robo-reviewing, those reviewers accept almost anything you throw at them).

Keep in mind that 3 reviewers need to approve your edit. Once you reach 2K your edits are not reviewed but the general guidance still applies.

You should edit to make a best effort to improve everything there is to fix in the post. This can include:

- correct the capitalization of I
- [Remove Hi, Hello etc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
- [Remove *Thanks in advantage* and variants](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)
- [fix all spelling/grammar/layout](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/145920/is-it-time-to-do-something-about-spelling-and-grammar)
- [improve the title](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)
- Add missing tags
- Remove irrelevant tags
- ... [*fix everything there is to fix*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/202178/158100) ...

and summarize your actions in the suggested edit comment.

The goal you should strive for is to fix as much as you can, reducing the need for subsequent visitors to edit again.
If you see issues but are unsure how to fix either refrain from editing or make that clear in your suggested edit comment.

Notice that some of your edits ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9932696), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9932069), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9920075)) got rejected because the OP edited the post. Their edits always take precedence and so do [edits of users with more then 2K](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

Comment: I understand better now.

Comment: A silly and arbitrary requirement that hurts the community as a whole.

Comment: @GEOCHET why does that hurt?

Comment: When you discourage good edits because they don't meet your capricious editing standards, or because the person wants to fix a quick and simple thing without investing all of their time into a single post, that hurts the community. There is a cost to policies, and there is a cost to arbitrarily discouraging people who fix content.

Comment: Hmm, but I'm not discouraging good edits. I try to explain that an edit should be complete and not partial @GEOCHET. If I need to be more clear about that let me know.

Comment: @rene - I came across one today who was a [robo-rejecting](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9942279).

Comment: That wasn't me this time @theB

Comment: @theB: Having had a look, that's a definite Meh suggestion. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9942045) is the one you should have posted.

Comment: @deduplicator It fixes a dead link. I may have used the wayback machine for the edited link. You'd have rejected?

Comment: @theB: The link isn't dead, just auto-redirecting. Do you expect that redirector to die anytime soon? Well, it looses the anchor on redirecting, so maybe it's actually worth keeping.

Comment: @deduplicator you're absolutely correct. I think I'm mixing up that one with another edit. Now that you point that out I'm kinda meh about it too. Losing the anchor isn't a huge deal really since people should know how to work their scrollbars.

Comment: Telling someone that they should only edit as long as they edit all of your criteria as well is definitely discouraging good edits.Being purposely obtuse does not change that.

Comment: @GEOCHET I edited your concern into the answer. Keep in mind that I'm giving this advice to get those edits passed reviewers that have the same attitude as I do. Let me know if I need to do more to address the issue you raised.

Comment: Are you really reviewing edits? "Loosing", "passed"?

Comment: I'm lost in how I can address your concerns without simply deleting the answer as you seem to disagree with some/all parts of my guidance. Your last comment seem to address my reviewing behavior. If your point is that I'm not reviewing enough suggested edits then you're correct. However, I want my advice to be inline with [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308717/578411). Any direction if I succeeded in that @GEOCHET

Comment: There seems to be a complete disconnect from anything I say with whatever you interpret. How can you be an effective editor or edit reviewer?

Comment: I don't know but it brought me where I am now but I share your concern about my effectiveness. Probably doesn't help that I'm not a native speaker. Do you see a way to sort out my disconnect? Would a chat session help, @GEOCHET ? Or if you see fit to edit  and expand my answer so it addresses your concern?

Comment: @GEOCHET I assume [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/190612/158100), [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155419/is-it-a-good-idea-to-either-drop-requirement-for-a-limit-of-6-character-for-edit/155453#155453) and [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169183/what-to-do-about-users-who-search-for-spelling-mistakes/169202#169202) answer of yours is similar to what you try to explain to me, right?

Answer (score 4):

Rene's [excellent answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308611/5240004) covers the general rules for reviewing, but I think that a case study might be a worthwhile exercise for you and for other people who come to this question in the future. As of this post you have 5 rejected edits. Of the 5, if they ended up in my review queue, there would have been 1 <kbd>Accept</kbd>, 2 <kbd>Improve</kbd> (counts as an accept in your stats), 1 <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>, and 1 <kbd>Reject</kbd>.

So without further ado, here comes the review.<sup>1</sup>

1. [Dividing Ground-penetrating radar profile through image processing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9920075)

   Rejected by Community♦ because of a conflict.  You also missed the image link which should have been inlined (`[text][1] -> ![text][1]`) and the naked dropbox URL which should have been turned into a link and moved to the bottom of the question.

   My opinion: <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd>
   Deduplicator's Opinion: <kbd>Improve</kbd>
2. [rdf jena api compared subject predicate object](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9932069)

   Rejected by Community♦ because of a conflict. You missed the word `proopriété` and some minor grammar tweaks. Also the title is a bit of a mess.

   My Opinion: <kbd>Improve</kbd>
   Deduplicator's Opinion: <kbd>Improve</kbd>
3. [xamarin ios uilabel issues](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9932696)

   Rejected by Community♦ because of a conflict. The code block has some extra spaces, and the title is ugly.

   My Opinion: <kbd>Improve</kbd>
   Deduplicator's Opinion: <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> "The edit is completely useless but there's an easy high-impact edit possible."
4. [How to process to move MySQL slave to “new” MySQL Slave server (migration)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9932811)

   This one is polishing a turd, and probably a question for Server Fault or Super User.  I wouldn't have even bothered with making the edit, because that could have kicked it out of the queues and disputed flags that may have been attached.

   My Opinion: <kbd>Reject</kbd>
   Deduplicator's Opinion: <kbd>Reject</kbd>
5. [In Qualtrics, how can I substitute a keyboard press for the next button?](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9945871)

   Rejected by Community♦ because of a conflict. A 2k+ user made an edit to the post while yours was pending. For what it's worth, the editor did exactly the same thing that you proposed.

   My Opinion: <kbd>Accept</kbd>
   Deduplicator's Opinion: <kbd>Reject</kbd> "Not worth it."

---

*<sup>1</sup>Yes, I am proud of that rhyme.*

Comment: Excellent explanation of all my rejected edits!!!!

Comment: 1. Improve 2: Concurr. 3. Unambiguously Reject&Edit: The edit is completely useless but there's an easy high-impact edit possible. 4. Concurr. 5. Reject, not worth it.

Comment: Dont give up on it. Just make sure that you edit things that are on topic, and are as good as you can make them. The majority of the rejects werent bad edits, but they could have gone farther.

Comment: In this case [In Qualtrics, how can I substitute a keyboard press for the next button?](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9945871) I don´t have nothing to do to avoid the rejection?

Comment: @deduplicator if you want I can make this cw and you can add your reviews to it. 5 is the one I probably would have skipped because I don't know enough about the framework.

Comment: Feel free to put my comment in there, but no need for CW.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Done.  And thanks for the better formatting.