# Did I suggest a bad edit or was it poorly reviewed?

Tags: discussion

I made a [moderately substantial edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16505957) to a post where the OP repeatedly used incorrect terminology. The incorrect terminology didn't affect the meaning of the post but made it unsearchable and less clear. I corrected the terminology and generally cleaned up the post a bit, but my edit was rejected. I'm confident that my changes to the terminology were correct (especially since my [answer was accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44713669/2288578)).

In an effort to improve my edit suggestions, did I suggest a bad edit (and if so, what's wrong with it?) or was the edit ok but the reviewers simply didn't take the time to realise that I wasn't changing the meaning of the post?

Comment: That's kind of a risky thing to do in a suggested edit because it can look like you're changing something instead of correcting it. That's probably how you got one of them saying your edit conflicted with the author's intent. (You should also be editing out things like "Thanks!" but since you removed the noise at the beginning I'm guessing that was an accident.)

Comment: You removed the _JS_ and _JSON_ from title. So the reviewer may think that this was an audit. Usually audits came in such a way...

Comment: @BSMP Well sometimes a simple "Thanks!" can be ok IMHO, but I don't know if there's any editing guidelines that say otherwise. Re the edit, I was _hoping_ when I made it that the reviewers would take enough time to realise that I wasn't changing the meaning of the post, but I also realise that the suggested edit queue is full a lot of the time so I assume the reviewers have their work cut out for them. Idk if anything could really be done about this.

Comment: @SagarV I hadn't considered that. That's a possibility for sure. Kind of amusing that people might start getting a sort of "audit sense". I wonder how often that would actually happen...

Comment: It's considered noise. As for the rest of the edit, the reviewers still have to agree with you that you weren't changing the meaning of the post. Sometimes people use edit summaries that don't match what they actually changed. And you can't bank on reviewers being familiar with every language in the edits they look at. I personally would have skipped an edit like this in a language I'm not familiar with and let someone who would be sure judge it.

Comment: @Clonkex read some here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/308611/2427065

Comment: @BSMP True. I guess I was just worried that I did the wrong thing by trying to correct the question's terminology, but no one has berated me for that (yet) so I'm feeling less worried :P

Comment: @SagarV That's good info, thanks :)

Comment: Removing the `[ecmascript-6]` tag was not necessarily a good idea. I would have rejected for that, because it helps let people know what language features can be used (for instance, in this case it might have been easier to use `Object.keys()` and `reduce` than a `for` loop).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Aha, now _that_ is a good point. I think I was assuming it wasn't relevant to the question (which it wasn't directly), but I can't have known whether the OP knew that they had access to ES6 features which could have been used in the answers, as you say. So I'll have to think more carefully about how the tags could be relevant before removing them.

Comment: @Clonkex as one of the people that reviewed the edit, my main problem was your removal of the `[ecmascript-6]`, also slightly the `[json]` tag but that was less important. On top of that, while the terminology wasn't correct in terms of JS (objects and properties rather than json and rows), within the context of json, the change from the json terms to the JS terms didn't *particularly* improve the quality of the question, I didn't find it easier to read and felt that leaving it in a format the OP was comfortable with was important. Note that this is just IMO, I wouldn't call this a bad edit.

Comment: @NickA Yep it's been pointed out to me that I shouldn't have removed the `ecmascript-6` tag and I definitely agree, but regarding correcting the terminology, I felt it more important that the question be useful to future searches and get a correct answer than remain how the OP wrote it. I believe that's the point of SO, to ensure that questions and answers are searchable and don't have to be asked twice. Maybe I took that too seriously, idk.